# Container views set height depending on children

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Here is my problem. I have this storyboard : [image: storyboard]
The first container must have a fixed height. It is related to the DetailFormViewController with the switch. I do not want it to be scrollable.

The second container must have a dynamic height, i.e. take the available height. It will show uitableview.

Here what I have on iPhone 6 : [image: iphone 6] and on iPhone 5S : [image: iphone 5S].

I have 3 questions :

1. Why is there a blank space at the top of the DetailFormViewController tableView ?
2. How can I remove it and I can I achieve my goal ?
3. Do you think that the layout I put is the best way to achieve what I want (based on the iPhone 6 screenshot) ?

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Do you have adjustScrollViewInsets on in IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making the top container height to be fixed and the bottom container to be flexible. To keep only 4 rows in top container, set the top container height constraint value as equal to 4cells height(4 * cell height).

You need to add constraints on two containers as like follows:

I have named first container as Top Container View and  2nd container as Bottom Container View.

```
  Top Container View constraints:
     - Top Space to Top Layout Guide
     - Leading Space to container
     - Trailing Space to container
     - Vertical Space to Bottom Container View
     - Height

  Bottom Container View constraints:
     - Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide
     - Leading Space to container
     - Trailing Space to container
```

Constraints are mentioned in this figure:
[image: Constraints on Container views]

Setting the height of the Top Container View defines that the top view height is fixed and the Bottom Container View's height becomes flexible.

iPhone 4s Portrait:

[image: iPhone 4S Portrait Layout with above set constraints]

iPhone 4S Landscape:
[image: iPhone 4S Landscape layout with same constraints]

iPhone 5S Portrait:

[image: iPhone 5S Portrait layout with same constraints]

iPhone 5S Landscape:
[image: iPhone 5S Landscape layout with same constraints]

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have Adjust Scroll View Insets enabled in your view controller.

[image]